# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Tags: python

O meu problema é o seguinte: eu quando vou executar o código de um exercício dá-me  um erro que não estou a perceber o porquê dele acontecer.

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

```
produtos = input('Lista com produtos:')
quantidade = input('Lista com quantidade:')
preco = input('Preco dos produtos:')
def sub_total(produtos,quantidade, preco):
    z = 0
    for x in range(len(produtos)):
        print (produtos[x], quantidade[x]*preco[x],'eur')
        z+=quantidade[x]*preco[x]        

    print ('Total:',z,'eur')    
sub_total(produtos, quantidade, preco)
```

Obs.: Os produtos, a quantidade e o preço devem ser executados em listas.

Comment: Trata-se de Python 2 ou 3?

Comment: Trata-se do python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `input()` não devolve uma lista, e sim uma string. É necessário quebrar a string nos espaços, gerando uma lista de strings, e depois transformá-las em inteiros, para que possam ser realizadas operações aritméticas com eles:

```
produtos = input('Lista com produtos:').split()
produtos = list(map(int, produtos))
quantidade = input('Lista com quantidade:').split()
quantidade = list(map(int, quantidade))
preco = input('Preco dos produtos:').split()
preco = list(map(int, preco))
```